# StackOverflowException on recursive anonymous functions

Tags: c#, recursion, anonymous-function, stack-overflow

I'm trying to write a function to check whether a string is a palindrome, and using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1208726/1327244), I'm trying to reverse the string using a recursive anonymous function:

```
static Boolean checkPalindromeAnonRec(string str)
{
    str = str.ToLower().Replace(" ", String.Empty);
    Func<string, string> revStr = null;
    revStr = delegate(string s) 
      { 
        if (s.Length > 1) 
          { return revStr(s) + s[0]; } 
        else 
        { return s; } 
      };

    return (str == revStr(str));
}
```

But every time I run it I get a `StackOverflowException`. It's not obvious to me why, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this is the problem:

```
if (s.Length > 1) 
  { return revStr(s) + s[0]; }
```

Aside from the odd bracing style, that's just recursing *with the original string* - so it will keep going forever. I suspect you meant to use `Substring` somewhere so that it recursed using a shorter string...

I would actually try writing it as a simple *non-anonymous* (but still recursive) method to start with - so work out how you would recursively write:

```
static string Reverse(string input)
```

... then if you still want to inline that into your `CheckPalindrome` method, you can do so.

Comment: How embarassing. Should have been `return revStr(s.Substring(1)) + s[0]` all along.

Comment: Just tried it out. It actually performs better with a named function than with the anonymous function

Comment: +1. And when you are done with fixing code make it properly anonymous recursion: [Anonymous Recursion in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx)