# In C#, how can a closure reference itself?

Tags: c#, closures

In C#, how can a closure reference itself? The use case is to automatically unsubscribe from an event, after a single occurrence (or on some condition). I know you can create an instance of a delegate, but I'd really like to keep this as a closure, to maintain context. For example:

```
var someVar = new FooBar();
textBox1.TextChanged += (s, e) => {
    doSomething(someVar);
    // Unsubscribe from further events
    // textBox1.TextChanged -= myself?
    // If I don't unsubscribe, I'm needlessly keeping reference
    // to someVar, and I don't intend to keep triggering this code
    // upon further events.
};
```

Comment: I believe you'll have to actually put `doSomething` in an actual event, as you cannot remove the subscription with this; `textBox1.TextChanged = null`. So you'll need an actual method / event to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it cannot reference itself directly.  However, you do something like this instead:

```
var someVar = new FooBar();
EventHandler closure = null;
closure = (s, e) => {
    doSomething(someVar);
    // Unsubscribe from further events
    // textBox1.TextChanged -= myself?
    // If I don't unsubscribe, I'm needlessly keeping reference
    // to someVar, and I don't intend to keep triggering this code
    // upon further events.
    textBox1.TextChanged -= closure;
};
textBox1.TextChanged += closure;
```

**Credit:** [Can an anonymous method in C# call itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208703/can-an-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp-call-itself)

Comment: That probably should be `Action<object, TextChangedEventArgs>`

Comment: Actually, the type should be simply `EventHandler`

Comment: Or `TextChangedEventHandler`

Comment: Good point.  I was showing the rough idea, however I will make the appropriate edit so it is more accurate.

Comment: Seems that TextChangedEventHandler is defined in the PresentationFramework assembly.  For this example I will just assume WinForms or maybe even WebForms.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx